# Countdown timer wont display onTick

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I'm having an issue where **my code won't display the onTick method**, and each time the counter is run, it simply displays the text "Done", as it should when it's finished. It seems that the endTime variable isn't being passed to the timer class? Any help with what I'm missing would be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private long endTime;
private MyTimer mainTimer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Set up the two number pickers
    NumberPicker minutes = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
    pickerSetup(minutes);
    NumberPicker seconds = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
    pickerSetup(seconds);

    mainTimer = new MyTimer(this, endTime, 1000);
}

public void pickerSetup(NumberPicker pickerId){
    pickerId.setMaxValue(60);
    pickerId.setMinValue(0);
    pickerId.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
}

public void calcTime(View view){
    //Get value of Number pickers and convert to milliseconds from minutes and seconds.
    NumberPicker minutes = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
    int selectedMinutes = minutes.getValue() * 60000;

    NumberPicker seconds = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
    int selectedSeconds = seconds.getValue() * 1000;

    //Add selected Minutes and seconds together
    endTime = selectedMinutes + selectedSeconds;
    Log.v("End time = ", String.valueOf(endTime));
    mainTimer.start();
 }
}
```

**timer class:**

```
class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer {

private Context mContext;
private TextView mToUpdate;


public MyTimer(Context context, long startTime, long interval) {
    super(startTime, interval);
    mContext = context;
    TextView toUpdate = (TextView) ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.intervalTimer);
    mToUpdate = toUpdate;
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
    int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    mToUpdate.setText(String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds));
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    mToUpdate.setText("Done");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are not initialized endTime when the time of calling `mainTimer = new MyTimer(this, endTime, 1000);` . It is set to 0 and that is why it stops as starts. You can change the two methods into something like this.

```
public long calcTime(View view){
    //Get value of Number pickers and convert to milliseconds from minutes and seconds.
    NumberPicker minutes = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
    int selectedMinutes = minutes.getValue() * 60000;

    NumberPicker seconds = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
    int selectedSeconds = seconds.getValue() * 1000;

    //Add selected Minutes and seconds together
    endTime = selectedMinutes + selectedSeconds;
    Log.v("End time = ", String.valueOf(endTime));
    return mainTimer.start();
 }

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Set up the two number pickers
    NumberPicker minutes = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
    pickerSetup(minutes);
    NumberPicker seconds = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
    pickerSetup(seconds);

    endTime=calcTime();
    mainTimer = new MyTimer(this, endTime, 1000);
    mainTimer.start();
}
```